# Polar pgfplots radial axis tick labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, polarplot

I want to overlay Cartesian axes on a polar plot. The vertical axis sits on top of the polar radial (horizontal) tick label. How can I move the tick label(s) so they are below the horizontal axis or otherwise out of the way?

[image: Notice "t" axis overlaying "0"]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.polar} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{polaraxis}[axis on top, xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$]
    \addplot[fill=green!40,draw=none,domain=-60:60]{1};
    \coordinate (origin) at (axis cs:0,0);
  \end{polaraxis}
  \draw[thick,blue,-stealth] (origin) -- +(0,1) node [above right] {$t$};
  \draw[thick,blue,-stealth] (origin) -- +(1,0) node [midway, above] {$s$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the alignment of the tick marks by setting `ytick align=outside`, and adjust the position of the tick labels by setting `yticklabel style={
        anchor=north,
        yshift=-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length}
    }`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.polar} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{polaraxis}[
    axis on top,
    xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$,
    ytick align=outside,
    yticklabel style={
        anchor=north,
        yshift=-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length}
    }
    ]
    \addplot[fill=green!40,draw=none,domain=-60:60]{1};
    \coordinate (origin) at (axis cs:0,0);
  \end{polaraxis}
  \draw[thick,blue,-stealth] (origin) -- +(0,1) node [above right] {$t$};
  \draw[thick,blue,-stealth] (origin) -- +(1,0) node [midway, above] {$s$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't get this to work. If I do this in my full paper, I get an error `! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfmath@dimen@ ...men@@ #1=0.0pt\relax \pgfmath@` (I see the \makeatletter but it doesn't seem to matter where I put that or if it's not there at all); if I LaTeX either of the MWE files here (including the one I was able to LaTeX a few days ago that I posted) I get `! Package PGF Math Error: You've asked me to divide `195.0' by `0.0', but I can not divide any number by `0.0'.` I have not updated texlive or any TeX packages since I posted this question.

Comment: @Liam: Sorry, the `\makeatletter` wasn't supposed to be there. So just by introducing `ytick align=outside,
    yticklabel style={
        anchor=north,
        yshift=-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length}
    }`, you introduce the error? That's really strange. What version of PGFPlots are you using?

Comment: Actually, it's just the `yshift=...` part; it works OK with `ytick align` only (but of course doesn't look right). My pgfplots version is `cc2f2d2dbac8 Tagged version 1.5`. I don't use anything newer because I can't find anything that works (I get an error about undefined control sequence `\pgfplotsversiondate`).

Comment: Can you try using `yshift=-0.3cm` (that corresponds to the default value of `major tick length`)?

Comment: Yes, that works.