# Pgfplots quarter-circle polar axis: drawing ticks on the 0-degree axis instead of 90-degree

Tags: pgfplots, polarplot

I've drawn a quarter-circle polar axis with pgfplots. However, the ticks are drawn on the 90-degrees axis whereas the tick labels are drawn on the 0-degrees axis. Can I fix this with pgfplots options?

In this picture, I've circled the ticks and drawn lines where I'd like them to be instead:

[image]

Code used to produce the above:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{polaraxis}[
    width=10cm,
    height=10cm,
    grid=both,
    grid style={dotted},
    xmax=90,
    ymax=7,
    ylabel=y label,
    ylabel style={yshift=-5mm, anchor=north},
    xtick={0,22.5,45,67.5,90},
    xticklabels={0$^\circ$,,45$^\circ$,,90$^\circ$},
  ]
  \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not found anything in the chapter on `polar` in the documentation. There seems to be the problem with 5.10.6 "Partial Polar Axes" as well (see image below).

[image]

But, after looking into the code, I found the option `ytick pos=left`, that gives the desired result.

### Variant 1

#### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{polaraxis}[
        width=10cm,
        height=10cm,
        grid=both,
        grid style={dotted},
        xmin=0,
        xmax=90,
        ymax=7,
        ylabel=y label,
        ylabel style={yshift=-6mm, anchor=north},
        xtick={0,22.5,45,67.5,90},
        xticklabels={0$^\circ$,,45$^\circ$,,90$^\circ$},
        ytick pos=left,
    ]
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]

### Variant 2

Using some code of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153888/123129) you could also put the numbers outside.

```
yticklabel style={
    anchor=north,
    yshift=-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length}
},
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!